# Change terminal in Atom-editor's Platformio-Ide-Terminal on Windows

Tags: atom-editor, platformio

On Windows, default terminal for [Atom's Platformio-Ide-Terminal](https://github.com/platformio/platformio-atom-ide-terminal) is Powershell (at least, that is what I get without any configuration).

I would prefer a terminal using unix-type commands. I already have MINGW and CYGWIN installed.

How can I avoid opening a Powershell and opening another terminal type instead?

Comment: Seems that I can set the terminal in *Settings>>Packages>>Platformio Ide Terminal>>Settings>>Shell Override*. But it open the terminal outside of atom as a new window.

Comment: I was pointing to mintty.exe, a terminal emulator. Must use a shell instead.

Answer (score 20):

Set the default shell in:
*Edit>>Settings>>Packages>>Platformio Ide Terminal>>Settings>>Shell Override*

You can use the git's bash as proposed [here](https://github.com/platformio/platformio-atom-ide-terminal/issues/81) as you probably already have git installed.

```
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe
```

Comment: The Shell Override option is not showing up on my screen, after I install platformio :/ any clues?

Comment: OOps, I was looking at the wrong "platformio" extension. The Shell override option appears in platformio-ide-terminal, specifically. Silly question, sorry

Answer (score 3):

**Step by Step Solution**

1. Go the Setting-> Packages -> In Search Bar, search for the platformio.
2. Open platformio and go to Shell Override Option.

Put the following line as per as your Terminal Requirement

For cmd- `C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\cmd.exe`

For Power Shell- `C:\\WINDOWS\\Sysnative\\WndowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe`

For bash- `C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe` or `C:\\Windows\\System32\\bash.exe` (depending on how you install the bash). Be Sure, that you have already install the bash into your computer.

Now, you can integrate bash, cmd, git bash, Power Shell into Atom using platformio as terminal.

Answer (score 1):

For CYGWIN users, the bash executable from the following location has proved useful for setting the shell override `Settings >> Packages >> Platformio Ide Terminal >> Settings >> Shell Override`

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are now using Ubuntu for Windows 10 (downloaded from the app store), you can change it to that as well.

Ubuntu gets installed in Windows' PATH by default, so just change the default shell to:

```
ubuntu.exe
```

That's it. Just remember that to get to your code, cd to /mnt/(driveletter)/wherever/your/files/sit.

Comment: Did not know that ubuntu is now a windows application. Nice!

Answer (score 0):

For someone who still can't get this to work because your git bash is installed in AppData. This worked for me.

C:\Users\saurabh\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\bin\bash.exe