# Need to update shell in PyCharm to zsh

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, pycharm, editor

Started taking the 'Programming for everyone' course on Coursera to learn python. Ive downloaded 2 text editors. Atom and Pycharm. When I open the terminal both say, "The default interactive shell is now zsh. To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`."

Please understand I'm totally new. This is the first time I've ever used a text editor or terminal so don't know where to run this or how to straighten this out. Im using a 2015 MacBook Pro running 10.15.7[Image is screenshot of editor and terminal in pycahrm im in.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9502O.png)

Comment: I was not aware that Atom by itself chooses a certain shell for its purpose. I think you can [configure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42277302/change-terminal-in-atom-editors-platformio-ide-terminal-on-windows) it according to your taste. While I personally prefer do zsh as interactive login shell, you should not let a text editor dictate to you what shell you are going to use. If you use, say, fish or bash interactively and are happy with it, I don't see why you should change your login shell.

Comment: I have zero experience with a text editor so don't understand what I need to do to run any code from the text editor in the local terminal. I don't really care what I use but when I try to run something I get, "To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`" I don't know where I need to run that or how. Or what I need to do to run any of the other shells you mentioned.

Comment: It's a matter of taste, but I never run code "out of the editor", although I am aware that some developers find it convenient. I use the editor to edit the code, and have my terminal open to run the code. I personally find this simpler than having the editor somehow setting up an environment for me. If you want to stick with configuring the editor in a suitable way, please ask this question at [su], because [so] is for programming problems.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it sucks. I had the same problem with Pycharm, but this solution worked for me.

1- Change zsh to bash

```
$ /bin/bash
```

2 - Get the commands back like (cd, ls, clear ...)

```
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin
```

3 - Get the profile back

```
. /etc/profile
```

After that your porfile will look like this "username:" instead of this "%n@%m %1~ %#"

One more thing, if you using mac, open your terminal and check **preference**. In the preferences go to **General** -> **Shells open with** -> if it is **Default Login shell** which means you are using *zsh*, you should change to **Command (complete path):** and add */bin/bash* in the space below so that your default change to bash.

I hope it was useful for you, and for the people looking for answers. Cause, I wasted an hour looking for solution that JetBrain Pycharm and Apple couldn't provide.